# recovery using WAL in Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Could anyone please tell me how recovery works in Hbase?

I have discovered the WAL file wherein every operation of HBASE needs to be logged in(/hbase/.logs/). But unfortunately that file is empty. None of the operation that I perform are logged into the WAL file. What could be the reason? Do I need to set any configuration variables? How do I enable it so that all the operations on HBase are regularly logged in?

By default, the write to WAL is enabled(put.getWriteAheadLog() returns a true value).
I am using "stand-alone mode" for HBASE setup.

Comment: I haven't used Hbase in particular, but WALs typically only contain data until it is written in to the datastore proper.  Perhaps HBASE is doing it very quickly so you miss it. Maybe it is skipping the wal since it is under such light load.  If you are able to query your data back out does it really matter?

Comment: The writes to WAL file is enabled. (put.getWriteAheadLog() returns a true value)

Comment: Thankyou for the quick reply. But that is exactly what I want to know. If my system crashes unexpectedly, I expect the WAL to write back my previous data... this doesn't happen but..! (basically bcoz nothing is saved in WAL.. I guess!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable WAL then only logs information will be written to WAL.
In your case it is not enabled.Please enable it and try again.

Regards,
Sudhakar Reddy

Comment: Reddy Kurakul: Thanks for the reply. The WAL is enabled by default. I had mentioned in the above comment. I had checked using "put.getWriteAheadLog()". It returns a true value. Is there anything else which I need to do?

Comment: I just discovered that, the entries get logged into the WAL after a long time. Where is this time controlled? The entries should be logged into the file immediately, isn't it? That's the whole point of a WAL right? Well, this is not happening in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve the problem in pseudo-distributed mode. It gets logged in immediately as soon as the data is written into the HBase tables. However, this behaviour is not seen in stand-alone mode. I was not able to figure out the parameter that controls the time.